# Yii2: How to display Multiple images in view from path saved in database?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have column called `images` in database which contain image paths.

Query:

```
$query = new Query;
                $todo = (new yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['images'])
                ->from('room_types')
                ->andWhere("id = '$model->id'")
                ->all();
```

View :

```
<?php
foreach ($todo as $row)
{
?>
<?php echo Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$row; ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Images path saved in db:

```
uploads/room_img/30.jpg;uploads/room_img/300.jpg;uploads/room_img/11928_569674493052762_732198968_n.jpg;
```

Tried with explode():

```
<?php 

function room_images() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT images FROM room_types WHERE id = $model->id");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $e[] = explode(" ", $row[0]);
            foreach($e as $r) {
                echo $r;
            }
        }
    }

 ?>
```

But nothing is showing

Comment: you need to explode images then use image tag.

Comment: show `$row` data also.

Comment: i have updated the question please look

Comment: I mean add what `$row` contains not how you use. Simple, print_r($row);

Comment: `Array ( [images] => uploads/room_img/969126_462708657170736_1165591713_n.jpg;uploads/room_img/969630_470510206377997_449434270_a.jpg;uploads/room_img/988881_1523318814563164_4726532938008911539_a.jpg; )`

Comment: Use [PHP explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and separate each image path then apply to  image tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `img` method of `Html` class -  [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#img()-detail)

In your view file

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
// ...
<?php foreach ($todo as $key=>$row): ?>

    <!-- html code if you need -->

    <?php
        foreach (explode(';', $row['images']) as $key_img => $value_img)
        {
            echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$value_img);
        }
    ?>

    <!-- html code if you need -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
// ...
```

Comment: still not working, path should be save like I mentioned in the question, is it right ?

Comment: In images column of one row you have semicolon separated image paths OR images column contains only one image path in a row?

Comment: having one row separated by semicolon for each image path